# show div in selecting option inside looping data

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

i have code in php:

```
<?php
$produk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produk ORDER BY id_produk DESC");
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($produk)){
    <select name='urutan'  onChange='yesnoCheck(this);'>
        <option value='yes' selected>Yes</option>
        <option value='no'>No</option>
    </select>
    <div id='ifY' style='display: none;'>
        <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
    </div>
    <div id='ifN' style='display: none;'>
        <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
    </div>
}
```

in my jquery code:

```
<script>
function yesnoCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "other") {
        document.getElementById("ifNon").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifNon").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (that.value == "yes") {
        document.getElementById("ifY").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifY").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (that.value == "no") {
        document.getElementById("ifN").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifN").style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

in my looping data,i try run selecting option to show div, but it just run in my first data,so cant run in another data. help me please

Comment: You're creating two divs for each $produk fetched so you can't use id='ifY' and id='ifN' because there will be duplicated ids.

Comment: i see,so what should i do?still confused hehe

Comment: add some number in php file while assigning id to div and also add extra parameter in yesnoCheck(this,$i) like this and while accessing document.getElementById("ifN"+number).style.display = "none"; so every div will have unique id

Comment: @WisdmLabs answer is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this should work

```
<?php
$produk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produk ORDER BY id_produk DESC");
$i = 0;
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($produk)){ ?>
<select name='urutan'  onChange='yesnoCheck(this,<?= $i ?>);' rel="<?= $i ?>">
    <option value='yes' selected>Yes</option>
    <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>
<div id="ifY<?= $i ?>" style='display: none;'>
    <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
</div>
<div id="ifN<?= $i ?>" style='display: none;'>
    <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
</div>

<br>
<?php $i++; } ?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function yesnoCheck(that,i) {
if (that.value == "yes") {
    $("#ifY" + i).css("display","block")
    $("#ifN" + i).css("display","none")
} else if (that.value == "no"){
    $("#ifY" + i).css("display","none")
    $("#ifN" + i).css("display","block")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help i guess. Also id should always be unique use class instead.

PHP code and html

```
<?php
$produk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produk ORDER BY id_produk DESC");
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($produk)){ ?>

    <div> // new div added here.
        <select name='urutan'  onChange='yesnoCheck(this);'>
            <option value='yes' selected data-selector="ifY">Yes</option> //  added new data-selector attribute.
            <option value='no' data-selector="ifN">No</option> 
        </select>
        <div class='ifY commonclass' style='display: none;'> // changed id to class and added a commonclass to get all divs.
            <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
        </div>
        <div class='ifN commonclass' style='display: none;'>
            <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Jquery

```
$('[name="urutan"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parentDiv = $this.parent();
    var $selected = $("option:selected",$this),
    $parentDiv.find('.commonclass').hide();
    $parentDiv.parent().find("."+$selected.data('selector')).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: what error you are getting in console? always respond with the error you are getting so that its easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dynamic ID and name for the div and select element with using counter variable.

PHP Code

```
<?php
$produk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manufacturer ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
$i = 1;
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($produk))
{
    ?>
    <select name='urutan<?php echo $i?>' id="urutan<?php echo $i?>" onChange='yesnoCheck("<?php echo $i?>");'>
        <option value='yes' selected>Yes</option>
        <option value='no'>No</option>
    </select>
    <div id='ifY<?php echo $i?>' style='display: none;'>
        <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
    </div>
    <div id='ifN<?php echo $i?>' style='display: none;'>
        <input type=submit value=submit class=ui-btn-primary>
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Javascript Code

```
 <script>
 function yesnoCheck(id) 
  {

    var that = document.getElementById("urutan"+id);
    /*if (that.value == "other") {
        document.getElementById("ifNon"+id).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifNon"+id).style.display = "none";
    }*/

    if (that.value == "yes") {
        document.getElementById("ifY"+id).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifY"+id).style.display = "none";
    }

    if (that.value == "no") {
        document.getElementById("ifN"+id).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ifN"+id).style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```